# Why coroutine stops working/executing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, countdown, coroutine

I have a 3 second countdown timer which is activated when game is unpaused. 
I had it working correctly a couple of days ago but now it doesn't work anymore. It gets blocked on the number 3. This is the code:

```
IEnumerator Timer() {

    Time.timeScale = 0;

    objectWithGSScript.scoreText.fontSize = 300;

    objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text = "" + 3;
    yield return WaitOneSecond();

    objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text = "" + 2;
    yield return WaitOneSecond();

    objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text = "" + 1;
    yield return WaitOneSecond();

    objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text = "Go!";
    yield return WaitOneSecond();

    Time.timeScale = 1f;

    objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text = objectWithGSScript.score.ToString();

}

IEnumerator WaitOneSecond() {
    float start = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < start + 1f) {
        print("entered");
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

It prints "entered" only once, it seems it exit from the coroutine, like it's returning null forever.

What could be the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hwo do you call this function?

Comment: @Programmer With StartCoroutine(Timer()).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function in your code is perfectly fine. No, it does not and should not stop at the number 3.

These are the possible reasons why it is behaving like it is getting stopped at the number 3.

**1**.You are calling `StopCoroutine` or or `StopAllCoroutines`. Please check that you are not stopping the coroutines. If you are when it is running, then it will behave this way.

**2**.You are destroying the script or GameObject this script is attached to. Check where you call the `Destroy(gameObject);`, `Destroy(this);` or something similar. If the script is destroyed, the coroutine should stop running.

Remember that you can destroy a script from another script so check all scripts.

**3**.You disabled the GameObject that his script is attached to. When you disable a GameObject, the coroutine stops working. Check that you don't have  `gameObject.SetActive(false);` or anything with `SetActive(false);` that disables that GameObject.

**4**.If you have a coroutine function in *ScriptA* and then starts that coroutine from *ScriptB*, if you destroy *ScriptB*, the coroutine from *ScriptA* will freeze at the yield return statement. It is important that you know this.

**5**. Null problem...

Maybe the `objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text` is not `null`. You must check **each** variable and make sure that they are not `null`. The `if` stametement is fine but a good shortcut is this:

```
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(objectWithGSScript);
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(objectWithGSScript.scoreText);
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text);
```

then you can do:

```
objectWithGSScript.scoreText.fontSize = 300;
objectWithGSScript.scoreText.text = "" + 3;
```

*I can't think of any other possible reason why this is happening but check all those five things mentioned above.*

Comment: Thanks man! I had the object deactivating itself automatically. Now it works! 
Thanks! Take a drink on my count! ;)

Comment: You know you can use `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);` instead of your `WaitOneSecond()` function? That should work too.

Comment: isn't it affected by Time.timeScale?

Comment: Nope. `WaitForSeconds` is affected by `Time.timeScale` but not `WaitForSecondsRealtime`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you a lot.